# PHP Post Restriction

Tags: php

I have a Wordpress blog site. User can send comments for my blog posts by **wp-comment-post.php**.

But some malicious users send a specific kind of POST which increases CPU and RAM usage. Probably they are converting text form submission into an file upload form and attach 1GB file or so.

Because comments are text, how can I restrict the POST submission for the **wp-comment-post.php** file as Text only? I also need to restrict the POST size as 5K or so because I think there is no need to post a comment in that size. If possible I need to control this POST behavior in and for **wp-comment-post.php** only without affecting POST behavior for other PHP files on my server.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135485/69683

.htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Careful, this may break unexpected things (like uploading your own media)

Comment: This appear to be site specific, isn't it? I need to restrict the limits for only wp-comments-post.php file without affecting other php files.